# How to print the output by using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have the below text in a file. From this if search for "Fileset", need to get the output until second "N". I have tried using awk and sed but not able to get the output as expected.

```
Job: name=jobname JobType=66 level= Priority=10 Enabled=1
     MaxJobs=1 Resched=0 Times=0 Interval=1,800 Spool=0 WritePartAfterJob=1
     Accurate=0
  --> Client: Name=clientname Enabled=1 Address=XXXXXX FDport=9102 MaxJobs=1
      JobRetention=14 days  FileRetention=14 days  AutoPrune=1
  --> Catalog: name=MyCatalog address=*None* DBport=0 db_name=bacula
      db_driver=*None* db_user=bacula MutliDBConn=0
  -->Fileset: name=test_host
     O MZof
     N
     I /u01
     N
```

From the above, need to get only below output.

```
Fileset: name=test_host
         O MZof
         N
         I /u01
         N
```

Tried below command

```
awk '/Fileset:/ {flag=1;next} /N/{flag=0} flag {print}' file
```

Where Fileset is pattern
/N/ is for end flag

Comment: from the sample input looks like you could also just print everything from `Fileset:` line? if not, it'd be better to add some more lines at the end

Comment: Why not just `grep -A4 Fileset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the second `N` to stop the processing, start flag with `2` when `Fileset:` is found, print lines while `flag!=0` and then decrement flag for each line with `N`.

```
awk '/Fileset:/{flag=2};flag;/N/&&flag{flag--}' file
```

Comment: Nice and clean. I would ask, though, if it shouldn’t be /^N$/ instead of just /N/

Comment: @mathguy Thank you. `/^N$/` is not an option because there are leading spaces, but `/^ *N *$/` is a more selective regex and probably better depending on the OP intent.